# Datagridview shows column from each SQL Server table in different order

Tags: c#, sql-server

I get a wrong datagridview rows order with this query

```
SELECT 
    E.*,
    TA.Numero_Transfert,
    Ta.Code_Transfert,
    TA.Numero_Agent,
    TA.Montant_Transfert,
    D.* 
FROM 
    Expéditeur E 
FULL JOIN 
    Transfert_Argent TA ON (E.Cin_Expéditeur = TA.CIN_Expéditeur) 
FULL JOIN 
    Agent A ON (A.Numero_Agent = TA.Numero_Agent)
FULL JOIN 
    Destinataire D ON (D.Cin_Destinataire = TA.Cin_Destinataire);
```

[image]

Comment: mysql **has no** full join, so your query will not work, please tag the correct rdms and post also a full [mre]

Comment: Do you really need 3 full outer joins? I can't remember the last time I used that many in a single query..

Comment: yes because i have three tables